# lwip netconn_recv netbuf overwritten from browser broadcast message

Tags: tcp, stm32, lwip

I have a project on a STM32H7 board with lwip 2.1.2 and freeRTOS V10.3.1 with a custom tcp server application running. So far I assumed that, when using netconn_recv(), the netbuf data are valid until the next netconn_recv() command. But sometimes it happens that an incoming BROWSER protocol broadcast message overwrites my rxbuffer and my application ends up with an error message, due to the corrupt data in the rxbuffer.
The error dos not occur, when I have wireshark running on the PC. But I can see artifacts of the broadcast message in the rx buffer when inspecting with the debugger.

My server loop is quite simple

```
while (running) {
    errRet = netconn_recv(current_conn, &rxbuf);
    if (errRet != ERR_OK) {
        break;
    }

    do {
        netbuf_data(rxbuf, (void*) &rxdata, &rxlen);
        if (netconn_receive (current_conn, rxdata, rxlen) != ERR_OK)
            break;

    } while (netbuf_next(rxbuf) >= 0);
```

}

I enabled the stack and heap overflow hook function, but there seems all ok.

Answer (score 0):

I found it out. I forgot to mention that my project is based on this STMCubeH7 repository application. So far I've been working with version 1.9.1, but now there's a newer version, v1.10.0. I did an update and it seems to  work now.
By the way, I found the repository log message: "Full rework of Ethernet HAL driver".